# How to get bcyrpt compare in a promise to work right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mariadb, bcrypt

I've had this working before, but now it's broken for some reason. I'm using `MariaDB` as a database, and need to compare passwords, but it's giving me an error `Unexpected Identifier on "bcrypt" after await`. When I remove the `await`, it works, but even if the password is wrong. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Edit:
I forgot to include the user info after .then.
I must of deleted it with some comments when I posted this question. I  added it back.
Here is my code:

```
//data connection pool
const pool = require('../models/db');
const { handleError, ErrorHandler } = require('../helpers/error');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  //destructuring assignment
  const {user_name, password} = req.body;
  let hashedPassword;
  //TODO: hash password

  var sql = `SELECT * FROM Govt_profiles WHERE
    (user_name = ?)`;

  //pool.query() is shortcut for pool.getConnection() + connection.query() + connection.release()
  pool.query(sql, [user_name], async (err, data) => {
  })
  .then(rows => {

    const user = rows.find( user => user['User_Name'] === user_name);
    if (user == null) {
      return res.status(400).send('Cannot find user');
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user['Password'])) {
        console.log('Password: ', password, 'hashedPassword: ', hashedPassword);
        console.log("this is a loginUser: ");
        console.log(req.session);
        //return res.redirect('questions')
        return res.render('user-progress', {
          userName: req.session.user_name,
          attempts: req.session.attempts,
          grade: req.session.grade
        })
      }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("something broke: ", e);
        res.status(500).send();
    }

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log("hey couldn't find user");
    req.session.error = new ErrorHandler(404, 'Incorrect email or last name');
    res.render('login_user', {
      //err: err (or if same name to this)
      //err
      error: req.session.error
    });
  })
}
```

I tried Lucas suggestion, and got this error:

```
C:\users\daniel\documents\git\usa-govt-quiz\controllers\loginUser.js:41
    const isValidPsw = await bcrypt.compare(password, user['Password']);
                       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\users\daniel\documents\git\usa-govt-quiz\server.js:5:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by putting a "async" in front of rows. This seems strange to me, and I don't know if this is normal, but it works.

Here's my final code from what I modified:

```
.then(async rows => {

    const user = rows.find( user => user['User_Name'] === user_name);
    if (user == null) {
      return res.status(400).send('Cannot find user');
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user['Password'])) {
        console.log('Password: ', password, 'hashedPassword: ', hashedPassword);
        console.log("this is a loginUser: ");
        console.log(req.session);
        //return res.redirect('questions')
        return res.render('user-progress', {
          userName: req.session.user_name,
          attempts: req.session.attempts,
          grade: req.session.grade
        })
      }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("something broke: ", e);
        res.status(500).send();
    }

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log("hey couldn't find user");
    req.session.error = new ErrorHandler(404, 'Incorrect email or last name');
    res.render('login_user', {
      //err: err (or if same name to this)
      //err
      error: req.session.error
    });
  })
}
```